why am I getting End-of-Day (EOD) Flush Errors in KDB RDB
While performing an EOD data flush in the RDB yesterday, we encountered an error that says sym. I have attached the error below. We have been using this in our tickerplant architecture without any issues for the past couple of months. However, we recently changed our table schema slightly because we were using the symbol type for incorrect columns, which caused significant memory usage. We changed these to char vectors for non-recurring columns, and this issue started happening after a week of running. Currently, we have two tickerplants running in production. The other tickerplant does not have this issue, and both setups are the same. The only difference is that in this tickerplant, the orders table has a big C as the type for the keyed column and not sym.



It's hard to make an exact statement about what might be wrong with your stack without being able to properly debug it. From the error shown, it looks like sym wouldn't exist. Did you delete the sym file on disk by any chance? Have you moved it? Also, from what you describe you have a couple of things wrong with your setup. 1. Your sym file is now bloated, making your queries slower and inefficient. You say this is only a few month old stack, I would consider deleting the HDB and regenerating the data. Alternative, you have to de-enumerate all columns, create a new sym file and enumerate them again. Here's a whitepaper about that process: https://code.kx.com/q/wp/symfiles/
2. Can you clarify what you mean with "keyed column" here "The only difference is that in this tickerplant, the orders table has a big C as the type for the keyed column and not sym." Because you can't splay keyed tables "Tables can be splayed. Keyed tables cannot." see Q4M https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb%2B/#1421-creating-splayed-tables
[Update] Are you passing the correct format to .Q.dpfts? https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#dpfts-save-table-with-symtable

Hey really thanks for helping me out.
Regarding your 1st point, our sym files are not huge anymore because we changed the schema that removed sym type for wrong columns.
This is our RDB code : https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cff2f82b95f50f6b
Regarding your 2nd point, in the code i sent you above it is doing unkeying before the .Q.hdpf ? i only key it back after the flush to HDB

So this error happened on production, then to reproduce it i tried taking the tickerplant log file from prod and tried to replay on my local RDB and did manual end of day. but no issue there

when i asked to devops sym file is not deleted nor moved. so the error really is no sym file ? that is indeed weird

keyed table meaning this one i meant https://code.kx.com/q4m3/8_Tables/#841-keyed-table
so RDB can update and insert data since all publishers are going to tickerplant first

our sym files are not huge anymore because we changed the schema that removed sym type for wrong columns  was a sym compaction done? changing the column types does not remove the unused symbols from the sym file. It's a separate step.

If this was a one off issue, Is it possible someone made a mistake and deleted the sym variable from memory?  A query like: delete sym from `.

@rianoc yeah man nobody admitted it yet, that query seems very odd for someone to execute, because in q console we know what queries are executed, so its definitely not that

on our prod RDB i typed sym its printed empty : q)sym
symbol$()

@rianoc that is weird because when replayed it on my local RDB wasnt empty at all

@works "our sym files are not huge anymore" --> there is only one sym file in the HDB, the one all symbol columns are enumerated against. Make sure to understand this concept well, if you are not sure, read chapter 14 of Q for Mortals which explains it. sym wouldn't be defined in the RDB, you need to check it in the HDB. The RDB has only intraday data, it's not enumerated

I looked at your RDB code, line 18, ```.Q.hdpf[$":",.u.x 1;hsym $"/home/kdb/tickerplant/matching-engine/hdb";x;`sym]; ```` if any of the tables you are trying to save down doesn't has a sym column then this would throw your sym error. That's my guess. Did you add a new table? in prod?
